# Error when importing Lacinia into Clojure project

Tags: clojure, pedestal

The Boot REPL returns this error

```
java.lang.Exception: No namespace: com.walmartlabs.lacinia.internal-utils
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.Exception: No namespace: com.walmartlabs.lacinia.internal-utils, compiling:(com/walmartlabs/lacinia/parser.clj:1:1)
```

when I try to run `(require :reload 'entrypoint)` in it. My namespace entrypoint has no code, only the `:require` function to import external code:

```
(ns entrypoint
  "Application entrypoint."
  (:require
    [clojure.java.io :as io]
    [com.walmartlabs.lacinia :as lacinia]
    [io.pedestal.http :as http]
    [clojure.java.browse :refer [browse-url]]
    [clojure.edn :as edn]
    [clojure.walk :as walk])
  (:import (clojure.lang IPersistentMap)))
```

My `build.boot` looks like this:

```
(set-env!
  :resource-paths #{"clj"}
  :dependencies '[[org.clojure/clojure                 "1.9.0"]
                  [com.walmartlabs/lacinia "0.21.0"]
                  [io.aviso/logging "0.2.0"]])
```

What am I doing wrong? D:

Answer (score 1):

My project was missing the `boot.properties` file.

I lost a couple of hours to notice this...